# facebook fbml application - How to make video autoplay?

Tags: facebook, video, fbml

I am writing down fbml in my facebook page, and I want the video to be autoplay while page loads.  I am using below code. But it is not working for me. Am I doing anything wrong here?

```
<fb:swf swfbgcolor="000000" imgstyle="border-width:3px; border-color:white;" swfsrc='http://www.youtube.com/v/xxxxxxxxxxx&autoplay=1' imgsrc='http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/1129/16631569.jpg' width='398' height='259' />
```

Comment: have you tried any of the solutions provided ?

Comment: tried, but did not work for me. Gave up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to autoplay a flash object you can use the `waitforclick` attribute of the fb:swf tag and set its value to `false`. For more info please check the [official documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/swf).

Be careful, autoplaying is not allowed in profiles mainly for security reasons, so don't try to use it there.